# Alternatives to iPXE

Tags: networking, boot, ipxe

may be I can get some help from the community.
I am in search of an alternative to iPXE and I am totally new to that topic.

The requirements for an alternative network boot solution (to iPXE) should be:

The goal is to provide a centralized network boot solution, thus creating the possibility of a client operating system or to be able to boot a recovery medium via network. Additionally, all required images should be made available in the PXE solution.

- The solution must be globally available and should be resource-saving.
- The solution can be run independently (no connection to the central system necessary)
- A flexible integration of different boot images is possible
  -The images should be available centrally and also locally by the departments (separately administrable)
- A dedicated rights and access management system should be integrated.
- The solution must meet the current security standard
- Central provision and central operation of the solution
- Standard support processes are offered
- UEFI & Legacy must be supported

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You are asking for a recommendation of software, has a lot of requirements, and the main goal is to get away from iPXE?

There might be solutions, but most of them will probably include iPXE.
What you are looking for seems to be a system that does a lot of management for you. iPXE is just a bootloader, all the other stuff needs to be external.

FOG project or 2Pint Software might have solutions for you.